# WorkbookA macro to create hyperlink in WorkbookB to call a macro in WorkbookA without Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I have encountered a fun (I think) problem.

- Let's say I have an .xlam Excel Add-In file which contains a macro
  (any macro), even let it be `Msgbox "Hello World!"`.
- Let's say that I run this Add-In on new Excel Workbooks each time
  (received from outside).

---

- I would like the Add-In to insert a hyperlink into the Excel Workbook that would be opened.
- I would also like that the inserted hyperlink would call the macro in the Add-In.

---

**Now what I know/what I've tried:**

1) If I was opening the same Excel Workbook each time I could just add the 'Follow Hyperlink' event: `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` into the Worksheet where I would like my hyperlink to be ran,

*however,*

Since I open a new file each time it's not going to have this piece of code in the Worksheet so the 'Follow Hyperlink' even won't work.

2) Now to solve the problem in point "1" I know that I could probably create another macro, which would insert the `Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)` code into the newly opened Excel Workbook i.e. **a VBA code which writes a VBA code**, *however I don't think that's a very elegant way of solving this problem.*

---

**To sum up:** I would like the (macro book) to insert a hyperlink into another workbook, and when that hyperlink would be clicked I would like it to run a macro from the 'macro book' WITHOUT using the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid you cannot... The hyperlink itself is not able to call a macro, from what I know. Usually, exactly the event you want avoiding does the job...

Comment: But it is not complicated to write exactly this `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink`event... It would be easier to be used then a `Sub` in a module, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the next simple way of accomplishing what you need, in fact:

```
Private Sub AddSheetEventCallProc()
   'It needs a reference to 'Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility x.x'
    Dim wb As Workbook, wProj As VBIDE.VBProject, wCom As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim wMod As VBIDE.CodeModule, Hrng As Range, LineI As Long

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'any existing workbook can be used here
    Set Hrng = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") 'use here the cell you need
    'Add the hyperlink:
    Hrng.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Hrng, _
            Address:="", SubAddress:=Hrng.Address, TextToDisplay:="Call Macro"
    With wb
        Set wProj = .VBProject
        Set wCom = wProj.VBComponents(Worksheets(1).codename)
        Set wMod = wCom.CodeModule
        With wMod
            On Error Resume Next
            LineI = .CreateEventProc("FollowHyperlink", "Worksheet"): LineI = LineI + 1
            .InsertLines LineI, "  If Target.Range.Address = """ & Hrng.Address & """ Then": LineI = LineI + 1
            .InsertLines LineI, "      Application.Run ""ADDINPRESA.xlam!testMsgbox""": LineI = LineI + 1
            .InsertLines LineI, "  End If"
            On Error GoTo 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The second (more elaborate) way will be to make your add-in create a new Ribbon Tab:

1. Having the addin, it is good to create a new standard module naming it 'modRibbon', or similar. It is not mandatory, but it is good to separate the ribbon specific module from the one doing the add-in job. So, in this one where you must create the `Subs` able to be called by controls of the newly Tab to be created:

   `Option Explicit`

   `Sub Test1(control As IRibbonControl)
       appTest1 'use here your Sub name
   End Sub`

   `Sub Test2(control As IRibbonControl)
       appTest2
   End Sub`

   `Sub Test3(control As IRibbonControl)
       appTest3
   End Sub`

It is useful to copy this code in a Notepad window, in order to use it when the xml file will be created.

2. Then, create the module where the Subs called by the above ones will exist:

   Sub appTest1()
       MsgBox "It's coming...", , "Test1"
   End Sub
   Sub appTest2()
       MsgBox "It's coming...", , "Test2"
   End Sub
   Sub appTest3()
       MsgBox "It's coming...", , "Test3"
   End Sub
3. Now, you need a, so named, OfficeRibbonEditor application. I use `OfficeRibbonXEditor` downloaded from [here](https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor/releases). Please, downoad 'OfficeRibbonXEditor-NETFramework.zip'. After downloading it, extract the file from archive and just use it. No installation need. 
   Now, run it and press `Open` button and browse for your add-in workbook and press `OK`. Select the open add-in and press 'Insert' menu. Select "Office 2010+ Custom UI Part" for Office 2010 or above. For 2007, select the other option. If you need the add-in to be compatible with both cases, both xml files will be inserted. I will show how to create a ribbon Tab only for first variant.
   Double click 'customUI14.xml`, which has been created and copy the next code. Now, it is assorted with the above subs, but, in order to make it call your specific subs, use the Notepad window where you copied the Subs name:

Now, **close the add-in from Excel** and press `Validate` Button. If you made a mistake in the xml code, the line with the mistake will be highlighted. If everything OK, press 'Save' button and open your add-in. It will create a new Ribbon Tab (`TestTab`) having three buttons....

4. There are on the internet ways to find all `imageMSO` types. It is also possible to use your own icons. I did it some years before. I do  not remember exactly how, but you need this option I can check my files archive.

For clarifying issues, a very good resource would be the Ron de Bruin site, which clarifies the way of doing such a Ribbon Tab, from more then ten years. You can find it [here](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm).

And the add-in does not 'import' the whole Ribbon. It only creates a new Tab adding it two the existing one and make it disappear when closed.

It is also good to know that when you modify the xml, all modifications done in the VBA add-in code will be lost and viceversa... That's why it is good to take care of closing the other one in the moment you modify something. If necessary, I can post a link to such an add-in done now, but, I would like to believe that it is easy to create one by yourself.

This is the way I create a new Ribbon Tab, but there are some other ways, too. When I will find some time, I will try doing it only in VBA. Practically, you have to read all subs you need to be called by your new Tab, then unzip the Excel file, create or modify the XML file in order to call your subs and rezip the file...

Comment: Yeah that's something along the lines I found while researching before I posted my question. I guess I would have to resort to this...however there is also one more problem with this solution: **namely** the project I'm working on for now is just for my personal use, however I would like to implement this for my co-workers and as you can imagine for somebody who has never seen VBA in their life asking them to add the reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility` is not really going to work.

Comment: I found a partial solution to the problem - instead of having any buttons to run the macro it would use the `Workbook_Open` event. So say: user downloads a macro-free Excel Workbook from their mail, they open it and then they start my Excel Add-In (.xlam) with the macro. The Add-In will run its macro on the other, previously opened Workbook when the Add-In is opened. This has the obvious disadvantage that the user has less control over when to run the macro.

Comment: I know the best solution would be to have a macro that would create a new **Ribbon Tab** in the opened Excel file, however I don't want to mess with the Ribbon as there is no easy solution to just `add one ribbon tab` and then to `remove that one ribbon tab` and the workarounds are far too complicated for me.

Comment: No any need for coorkers reference! Your add-in myst have such a reference. The coorker file, according to SO security settings, it is good to be in a trusted location. Even this can be done by your add-in, using VBA...

Comment: And yes, your add-in can create a new ribbon Tab, able to do what you need. I can show you how, but after 6 to 7 hours when I yill be home...

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos: So, would you like to show you how your add-in can create a Tab Ribbon, or you already did that? I like helping people, but I do not like loosing time. So, can you confirm that you still need such an answer? Even if your question does not ask for it...

Comment: Yes please, if there is a relatively easy method please either show me some short-version of this or direct me in the right way, thanks! So far everything I found about the ribbon were really extensive processes that involved lots of steps (and possibly third party software). Also I remember I found that you can't import a single tab into the ribbon. It can only be imported as a whole and it OVERWRITES the user's original one...which I obviously don't want :)

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos: It may look complicated, but it is not, in fact. After making your first Ribbon Tab, it will take you less then 10 minutes for the next one... It can be done without 'third party software', but **it will be much more difficult**. This software offers you the possibility to insert a .xml file, instead of building and adding it to the workbook. Starting with Office 2007, the workbook  is not a single file as in previous versions. If you change the extension (xlsm, xlam etc.) with zip, you can open the archive and see three folders and a lot of subfolders/files...

Comment: so you mean to use the 'RibbonX Editor' from rondebuin.nl ? And once I create the ribbon in there I will have to include in the code to only active it in that one workbook, right?

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos: Not really... The new Ribbon Tab will be created for the time of your add-in is open!. But, **all your add-in subs/functions will be accessible for all open workbooks**... It is enough to press its buttons. Of course, you will take care to refer the active workbook, Workbooks("xxx") and so on... And the Ribbon editor is not created by Ron de Bruin. Maybe he uses it in his last versions. I didn't check that. I followed his way more then 10 years ago. Maybe now he improved it. At the beginning, he was using one editor created by Microsoft.

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos: But, I would suggest tou to create a new test add-in, using the subs and xml from  my answer. Seeing it working will make it a simple to follow sample for your existing add-in, I think.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I will try to do that tomorrow or in two days. It's Sunday afternoon and I'm going to work tomorrow morning :)

Comment: @Danny Papadopulos: Good plan... I have a plan for a solution using VBA 100%. I have some projects now, but I will give it a shut in the next future. It is based on the fact that, creating a specific file (xml content) in a specific Office folder, it can modify the Ribbon, adding a new tab. But, it can be used only for one add-in... So, the best solution, wanting to use more then one add-in is the above described one, when the xml file is specific for each workbook...